# BeanStalkd on Solaris doesnt return anything when called from the python library

Tags: python, solaris, yaml, beanstalkd

i am using Solaris 10 OS(x86). i installed beanstalkd and it starts fine by using command "beanstalkd -d -l hostip -p 11300".

i have Python 2.4.4 on my system i installed YAML and beanstalkc python libraries to connect beanstalkd with python my problem is when i try to write some code:

import beanstalkc
beanstalk = beanstalkc.Connection(host='hostip', port=11300)

no error so far but when i try to do someting on beanstalk like say listing queues. nothing happens.

beanstalk.tubes()

it just hangs and nothing returns. if i cancel the operation(using ctr+c on python env.) or stop the server i immediately see an output:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in ?
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/beanstalkc-0.1.1-py2.4.egg/beanstalkc.py", line 134, in tubes
    return self._interact_yaml('list-tubes\r\n', ['OK'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/beanstalkc-0.1.1-py2.4.egg/beanstalkc.py", line 83, in _interact_yaml
    size, = self._interact(command, expected_ok, expected_err)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/beanstalkc-0.1.1-py2.4.egg/beanstalkc.py", line 57, in _interact
    status, results = self._read_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/beanstalkc-0.1.1-py2.4.egg/beanstalkc.py", line 66, in _read_response
    response = self.socket_file.readline().split()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/socket.py", line 332, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)

any idea whats going? i am an Unix newbie so i have no idea what i did setup wrong to cause this.

edit: seems like the problem lies within BeanStalkd itself, anyone have used this on Solaris 10? if so which version did you use? The v1.3 labeled one doesnt compile on Solaris while the latest from git code repository compiles it causes the above problem(or perhaps there is some configuration to do on Solaris?).

edit2: i installed and compiled same components with beanstalkd, PyYAML, pythonbeanstalc and libevent to an UBUNTU machine and it works fine. problems seems to be about compilation of beanstalkd on solaris, i have yet to produce or read any solution.

Comment: i just tried to connect beanstalkd with java client same thing happens, the test scripts just wait (till cancelled or beanstalkd stopped) forever. any ideas what might be wrong on Beanstalkd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might know what is wrong: don't start it in daemon (-d) mode. I have experienced the same and by accident I found out what is wrong.

Or rather, I don't know what is wrong, but it works without running it in daemon mode.

./beanstalkd -p 9977 &

as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the python-client listens to the server,
but the server has nothing to say.

Is there something to read for the client?

Is there a consumer AND a producer ?

[Look at this](http://parand.com/say/index.php/2008/10/12/beanstalkd-python-basic-tutorial/)

Comment: yes, there is something to read for the client, server is supposed to send tubes(beanstalk.tubes() call requests that) which is "default" tube, and its same with every other command i try to execute on beanstalk (beanstalkc.Connection object), no command seems to respond.

Comment: i looked at the link you send but i am not using pybeanstalk, i am using beanstalkc

Answer (score 1):

After looking in the code (beanstalkc):

your client has send his 'list-tubes' message, and is waiting for an answer.
(until you kill it)
your server doesn't answer or can't send the answer to the client.
(or the answer is shorter than the client expect)

is a network-admin at your side (or site) :-)

Comment: i also did install beanstalkd server too. i got the latest code for beanstalkd and compile it since the official v1.3 wasnt compiling on solaris. where exactly should i check for ensuring beanstalkd or network works fine? i can get my network-admin at my side, what should i ask him :)

Comment: 1. tell your network-admin what you want to do |
2. let yout network-admin check : connection and traffic / are there packets between client and server / which side (client or server doesn't work.

Comment: well both client and server running on the same machine, so i doubt if there is or need be any network activity.